# Stored query using array as parameter

Tags: database, ms-access

I have the following stored query in an MS Access DB:

```
PARAMETERS pNumber Long;
SELECT *
FROM entries
WHERE id IN ([pNumber]);
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
PARAMETERS pNumberArray Long Array;
SELECT *
FROM entries
WHERE id IN ([pNumberArray]); // pNumberArray = 33, 51, 84, 100
```

The array will be provided by VB6

Answer (score 1):

You need a slightly different approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM entries
WHERE InStr([pNumberArray],[ID])>0
```